# How to use if clauses on queries in iReport

Tags: ireport

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COUNT(*)  
FROM TABLE  
WHERE COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL  
    AND COLUMN4 = 1  
    AND COLUMN5 = 4  
    AND COLUMN6 = 43  
    AND COLUMN7 = $P{YEAR}  
    AND COLUMN8 = $P{IT}  
GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2  
ORDER BY COLUMN1 ASC
```

I wonder if it is possible to do something like:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COUNT(*)  
FROM TABLE  
WHERE COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL  
    AND COLUMN4 = 1  
    AND COLUMN5 = 4  
    AND COLUMN6 = 43  
    AND COLUMN7 = $P{YEAR}  
    IF ($P{IT} != 'ALL') { AND COLUMN8 = $P{IT} }  
GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2  
ORDER BY COLUMN1 ASC
```

In other words, I want to add to the where clause "AND COLUMN8 = $P{IT}" only if "$P{IT}" value is not "ALL". This means if the report must filter by the column "COLUMN8" or not.

Do someone know if this is possible? Is there other approach that accomplish the work?

I tried to execute the above query but I got a 'Compilation running time'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in iReport. But you need to look at it slightly differently. You need a second parameter. Keep $P{IT}, and add $P{IT_SQL}. Give $P{IT_SQL} a default value like this:

```
$P{IT}.equals("ALL") ? "" : " AND COLUMN8 = '" + $P{IT} + "'"
```

Then your query should look like this:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COUNT(*)  
FROM TABLE  
WHERE COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL  
    AND COLUMN4 = 1  
    AND COLUMN5 = 4  
    AND COLUMN6 = 43  
    AND COLUMN7 = $P{YEAR}  
    $P!{IT_SQL} 
GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2  
ORDER BY COLUMN1 ASC
```

That will give you the desired SQL (none!) when $P{IT} has the value "ALL", and it will give you the desired SQL (COLUMN8 = 'abc') when $P{IT} has the value "abc".

Comment: Thank you. What does it mean the exclamation mark after $P, $P **!** {IT_SQL}? Sorry, It's because I am almost new in iReport.

Comment: @madahlman I have done same thing but i got `Target Eception: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @Raghu, this implies that $P{IT} is null, and $P{IT}.equals() is throwing the exception. Make sure $P{IT} is initialized. Or perhaps you could reverse the logic: "ALL".equals($P{IT})  I find that harder to read/maintain, but it might avoid the NPE easily.

Comment: @mdahlman how to initialize that , I pass the value of that from my java program.

Comment: I tried with reverse the logic and I initialize by giving parameter default value then it is giving mysql error as`<col_name>=null`